# What type of result SQLAlchemy query() returns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a table in my database

```
class Operator(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(100))
    calls = db.relationship('Call', backref='operator', lazy='dynamic')
```

and I want to get all `login` from this table. So I do

```
operators = db.session.query(models.Operator.login).all()
print(operators)
```

And I suppose to get a list of `logins` but in fact I've got a list of tuples

```
[('ivanov',), ('petrov',)]
```

Of course I can manage this data but I can't understand why it's formatted in that way? Why it has empty second element in every tuple? Maybe I do something wrong and there is easier way to get list of `logins`?

Comment: It does **not** have a second element in the tuples. That's just how a single-element tuple is written. If it did not have the comma, it would just be regular parenthesis: `("foo")` is the same as `"foo"`.

Comment: Super late, but.. it appears you're not asking what type of result the QUERY function returns, but instead what type of result the ALL function returns. And I think the answer is, list of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of `login`s something like this will do what you need:

```
operators = db.session.query(Operator).all()
operators = [op.login for op in operators]
```

The tuple representation is the standard.